# What is the problem with Transfer function?

Tags: solidity, remix, crowdsale

Here, ERC20(token) - 'token' is given Undeclared identification issue, why?

```
// low level token purchase function
function buyTokens(address beneficiary) public payable {
    require(beneficiary != address(0));
    require(validPurchase());

    uint256 weiAmount = msg.value;

    // calculate token amount to be created
    uint256 tokens = weiAmount.mul(rate);

    // update state
    weiRaised = weiRaised.add(weiAmount);

    // transfer tokens purchased 
    ERC20(token).transfer(this, tokens); //

    TokenPurchase(msg.sender, beneficiary, weiAmount, tokens);

    forwardFunds();
}
```

Comment: Hi there. Do you have any imports in your contract that define it?

Comment: guys, I need you to explain how and where to define it. BY adding example to my code.

Answer (score 1):

You haven’t defined the token variable

[image]

Comment: OK. I could define the token. Now checking if test token works proeprly. WIll open another Question if sth goes wrong.

Comment: You should mark the answer as “answered” and attribute to the person who helped the score. It is one year ago you had the answer. What about that?